# How to convert xml objects to python objects?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

docs are always badly written, examples are more helpful.

this is my xml file:

```
<wordbook>
  <item>
    <name>engrossment</name>
    <phonetic><![CDATA[ɪn'grəʊsmənt]]></phonetic>
    <meaning><![CDATA[n. 正式缮写的文件，专注]]></meaning>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>graffiti</name>
    <phonetic><![CDATA[ɡrəˈfi:ti:]]></phonetic>
    <meaning><![CDATA[n.在墙上的乱涂乱写（复数形式）]]></meaning>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>pathology</name>
    <phonetic><![CDATA[pæˈθɔlədʒi:]]></phonetic>
    <meaning><![CDATA[n. 病理（学）;〈比喻〉异常状态]]></meaning>
  </item>
<wordbook>
```

this is my python class:

```
class Item(Base):
    name = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    phonetic = Column(String(50), default='')
    meaning = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)
```

choose the xml parser you like

---

finally, I use xmltodict to parse, lxml to write:

```
from lxml import etree

wordbook = etree.Element('wordbook')
for one in items:
    item = etree.Element('item')
    name = etree.Element('name')
    name.text = one.name
    phonetic = etree.Element('phonetic')
    phonetic.text = etree.CDATA(one.phonetic)
    meaning = etree.Element('meaning')
    meaning.text = etree.CDATA(one.meaning)
    if 1:
        item.append(name)
        item.append(phonetic)
        item.append(meaning)
    wordbook.append(item)
s = etree.tostring(wordbook, pretty_print=True, encoding='utf8')
print s
```

Comment: try to find examples in docs of beautifulsoup and on stackoverflow

Comment: "docs are always badly written" - yeah, no. The only thing I have to say to this is [RTFM](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml).

Comment: there are many examples in sqlalchemy's github source, so i can grep it, examples are best for beginners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with using [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xmltodict

data = """<wordbook>
  <item>
    <name>engrossment</name>
    <phonetic><![CDATA[ɪn'grəʊsmənt]]></phonetic>
    <meaning><![CDATA[n. 正式缮写的文件，专注]]></meaning>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>graffiti</name>
    <phonetic><![CDATA[ɡrəˈfi:ti:]]></phonetic>
    <meaning><![CDATA[n.在墙上的乱涂乱写（复数形式）]]></meaning>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>pathology</name>
    <phonetic><![CDATA[pæˈθɔlədʒi:]]></phonetic>
    <meaning><![CDATA[n. 病理（学）;〈比喻〉异常状态]]></meaning>
  </item>
</wordbook>"""

data = xmltodict.parse(data, encoding='utf-8')

for item in data['wordbook']['item']:
    print item['name']
```

prints:

```
engrossment
graffiti
pathology
```

You can also use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de) - it's a matter of taste. The idea is pretty much the same - iterate over `item` tags and instantiate `Item` in the loop.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to parse and write xml in java a year ago.

Comment: It's nice to learn xml parsing in minutes, with the help your example. A year ago, I spent a week or more.